# iMac running OS X 10.2.8 doesn't get an IP address on Wi-Fi

Tags: macos, network, wifi, imac

I just bought an old iMac (model identifier PowerMac6,1) running Mac OS X 10.2.8. Everything is working great except the internet connection. There is an Airport option for connecting to WiFi, so I'm assuming the iMac has the hardware/software capabilities required.

I can successfully connect to my AT&T U-verse WiFi (I select the network, put in my password, the Airport icon shows the signal strength, etc.) but I'm not connected to the internet. Every time I try to load a webpage, Safari alerts that the server can't be found. All my other devices are able to connect to my WiFi with no problems.

Is my iMac just too outdated to be able to fully connect to an AT&T U-verse WiFi connection? If not, how can I successfully connect?

**UPDATE**

Okay, when I go to System Preferences > Network on the old iMac, the TCP/IP tab is selected. Along with the following options:

Configure: Using DHCP
IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (self-assigned)
Subnet Mask: xxx.xxx.x.x
Router: --
DHCP Client ID (optional): -- 
AirPort ID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
DNS Servers (optional): xxx.xxx.x.xxx
Search Domains (optional): gateway.2wire.net

**UPDATE**

Connection info:
[image]

There were no devices in the MAC Filtering list

Comment: More Information Please:  Check out Apple Menu > System Preferences > Network.  Then click on the Wifi/Airport connection.  Tell us what you see there.

Comment: I'll add more info as soon as I can.

Comment: In a web browser can you get to http://192.168.1.254 ? That's the configuration page for the router, if you can get to that there might some setting in the router preventing your iMac from sharing the Internet connection.

Comment: @KevinSchumacher - Thanks that useful info. I'll check and update.

Comment: @KevinSchumacher - I can't get to that IP.

Comment: Can you get to it from any other device on the network? If not and you have an iPhone or iPad, on the device go to Settings > WiFi and tap on the blue circle with the arrow in it across from your WiFi network's name, then look at the setting for Router. What IP is listed there?

Comment: @KevinSchumacher - I CAN get to 192.168.1.254 from my iPhone.

Comment: Can we safely assume that the obfuscated values in your TCP/IP configuration are valid values?   Or are they blank/self-assigned values?    I see that you are set to use DHCP, that is a good start.  But please check that you are getting a valid address from your DHCP server.

Comment: @TheWellington - My IP address has a value, but I forgot to mention in my edit that it says '(self-assigned)' under the value.

Comment: OK... your Mac is _not_ getting an address from a DHCP server.  It is effectively not on your network.

Comment: Are you sure you have a device on your network providing DHCP?  What does your network look like?  I am not familiar with how AT&T U-verse is set up.  Do they provide you with a wireless AP?  Is it DSL to the house?  Do you have a DSL or Cable modem/router?   Do you then have a second wireless router?

Comment: More specifically, does your network look like this:  Cable or DSL connection --> Modem --> WiFi/Router/Switch --> your computers   ???

Comment: @TheWellington - Yes, I have a modem and router installed. The network looks like: Cable connection > Modem > Router > Devices

Comment: that didn't come through...   but I have looked up u-verse on the interwebs.   AT&T provided you with a residential gateway and it has wireless built in - didn't they?

Comment: Is your wireless router a 5GHz model?   It is likely that your 10.3 machine cannot access the 5GHz band.   Your router should also have the ability to transmit on the 2.4 GHz band.    It may also be labeled at 802.11b|g vs 802.11a|n   you will need to activate the b|g channel

Comment: @TheWellington - That sounds like a probable solution. If you'll post that as an answer, I'll try it and mark as correct if it works.

Comment: Perhaps it's a DNS problem? Try using Google's for a test: 8.8.8.8.

Comment: One simple suggestion, as it doesn't seem to have been mentioned so far: how about plug the iMac in via Ethernet?  (This would give another useful piece of information for the troubleshooting, and perhaps it might be a workable long-term solution if wiring permits?)

Comment: → hw731: from what you describe, you have a wireless connection established correctly, but you don't get a correct DHCP lease from your router. Do you have a `!` within the AirPort icon?

Comment: → hw731: how many black stripes are there within your AirPort icon? How many other wireless network do you see in the dropdown menu from the AirPort icon?

Comment: @danielAzuelos - There is no `!` character on the Airport icon. The Airport icon displays full bars most of the time, although I've seen it drop one bar occasionally. And I don't see any other networks in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @hw731 Is your access point using WEP, WPA, or WPA2?  If WPA2, TKIP or AES?

Comment: @zigg - Where can I go to find out?

Comment: @hw731 I'm not sure. It'd be part of your U-Verse gateway configuration, and I'm not familiar with them. But I do believe older Macs don't support some of the newer WPA standards, even though they still present a password prompt.

Comment: @zigg See my comments to the answer below, it explains where to find the security settings. I was actually headed down that same track. :)

Comment: → hw731: don't search a minute about which WEP, WPA or WPA2 is using your MacOS X, it does only support WEP (it's a shame), and as long as your AirPort icon display black lines, your password was accepted. Your problem is purely DHCP centric.

Comment: → hw731: you don't have a wireless interference problem, and you don't have a too weak SNR problem.

Comment: → hw731: do you have `tcpdump` on MacOS X 10.2.8 ?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Just FYI, I'm pretty sure the `!` character in the Airport icon is a fairly recent addition to OS X and wasn't in 10.2.

Comment: → Ashley: I'm pretty sure you're right ☺.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ancient WLAN adaptors only support none or (insecure) WEP encryption methods. Current router come with WPA/WPA2 preconfigured. For those cases like yours, virtually any routers support manually selecting WEP encryption. Try this.

While it's better than no encryption, it's benefits are close to zero. So make sure not to transfer sensitive data via WLAN while it's encrypted using WEP.

Comment: WEP == lie!
WEP isn't better than no security, it's worse.
Exactly as an empty extinguisher is worse than no extinguisher at all.

Comment: If you know the extinguisher is empty, you won't rely on it but you still can knock someone down with it.

Comment: Imagine you're a thief. What house would you break in? The one with the el cheapo Mickey Mouse gimmick style lock? Or into the house with the gaping wide open door?

Comment: → Max: fantastic allegory for WEP. The thief would target the Mickey lock: "They have something to protect, and they're really bad at it!". And he's well advised. Behind the open door is… ☺.

Answer (score 3):

If the iMac is indeed limited to WEP security, an alternative would be to use a 'wireless gaming adapter' such as [this one](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156310). Originally marketed to Xbox 360 users who did not want to buy the official wireless adapter, these devices handle the wireless connection (using stronger WPA/WPA2 security) and provide an ethernet connection to the iMac.

Answer (score 1):

## Simpler network configuration

To analyse this typical network problem, one has to first define a simpler network configuration so as to focuse on the problem to fix.
Here is how:
Within:

```
System Preferences > Network
```

select:

```
Location: Edit Location… > +
```

enter the name of a fresh configuration:

```
AirPort @ home
```

select it, and click `Done`.

Select every network interface, but the AirPort one, in the left subwindow and delete it:
[image: AirPort @ home configuration 1]

Your interface won't look as this screen capture made on a much recent
MacOS X, but the idea remains. This was working on the first Mac OS X: remove the useless network interfaces to be sure you are testing the only one you want to trouble shoot.

Configure the remaining AirPort interface:

```
Network name: *your home network name*
```

and upon request enter your WEP password,
select the bottom right `Advanced…` button and define the `TCP/IP`
as static with the following values (which should be correct for your network):
[image: AirPort @ home configuration 2]

Click `Apply` and confirm that the button on the left of the interface name (`AirPort`) switches to green within a few seconds.

## Tests

Once this configuration is up, open a `Terminal` and type the following command:

```
ping 192.168.1.254
```

to see if you can directly reach your router.

If this ping is OK, then the problem is on your router.

Next chapter depends of this test result.

Answer (score 0):

A machine running OS X 10.3 likely has an Airport card that cannot support modern WiFi connections in the 5GHz band, also known as 802.11n.  You may be restricted to WiFi connections in the 2.4GHz band, also know as 802.11b or 802.11g

Your router should be able to support both bands simultaneously.   You will need to look at your router's configuration and activate 802.11b|g while leaving the 5GHz band (802.11n) active for your more modern devices.

Comment: While this is a really good thought (and I'm jealous I didn't think of it lol), AT&T does not supply any U-Verse (2wire) gateways that support 802.11n. Therefore if he has WiFi coming from the gateway, it's already b or g.

Comment: I did some research and I think @KevinSchumacher is right. I don't think 2Wire routers support 802.11n anyway. Any other ideas? Still can't establish a connection.

Comment: Do you have any settings on the gateway that would prevent a new device from connecting? Go to your gateway's configuration then Settings > LAN > Wireless and look down towards the bottom at MAC filtering. Actually while you're there, is Wireless Mode set on b/g or just one of them?

Comment: @KevinSchumacher - Edited question with more info. Thank you all for your persistence.

Comment: Note: hw731 is running Mac OS X 10.2.8, not 10.3.

Comment: Also on the Wireless tab of the gateway, what type of security is it using? And how much RAM in the iMac?

Comment: @TheWellington 5 Ghz-WLAN is NOT modern. Actually it is available as 802.11a since 1999.

Answer (score 0):

While it is no help to the OP I am having similar problems on my modern Retina MacBookPro. Mac's used to be the envy of PC users in their effortless ability to glide from WiFi hotspot to WiFi hotspot, connecting seamlessly at each one, but increasingly I am failing to connect to third party signals, with similar symptoms.

Basically password is accepted, WiFi signal is strong, but there is no connection to the internet and I end up with a self assigned password, indicating a problem with DHCP handshaking.

Sometimes I can shake the tree by going into Network Preferences and clicking "Renew DHCP Lease" on the TCP/IP tab of the Advanced section of WiFi preferences. This forces the Mac to request a new IP address.

Occasionally I can make it work by entering a manual IP address if I already know the subnet of the router by looking on another computer.

However my point is this - I believe that of late Apple's TCP/IP stack and the WiFi implementation of third party vendors has started to diverge, perhaps over timeout periods, and I think the OP is having the same problem.

For $100 he could plug an Apple Airport Express into the U-verse and see if he can connect to that more cleanly?